# Error while updating

Tags: apt, software-center

I am a new Ubuntu user running 14.04 LTS and I have a question that has been bugging me for 2 days.

This is the error I get when I use $ sudo apt-get update:

```
W:Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release i386 (20160217.1)/buntu/dists/trusty/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'restricted/source/Sources' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
```

I booted the OS via a USB stick and I have no bootable disc. This leads to other errors that make me unable to download/install any new applications via software center.

Please help a newbie out and thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you copy the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`? Maybe you have some wrong sources there

Comment: The first line says Ubuntu cannot find CDROM containing Ubuntu. You can remove CDROM as the source of update by going to your System Setting > Software & update. The second one is related to some problem in the sources.list file. May you update your post and share the result of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: Let us know how you get on ... ?